# Allow users to visit main site when a screen size redirect command is given (HTML/.asp classic)

Tags: html, redirect, mobile, asp-classic

I have the main website which uses .asp code and i have a piece of code which redirects users to the mobile website depending on their screen size. The code is written below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 1024) {
document.location = "mobilewebsite.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

This is works fine and i have something sort of similar the other way around. The mobile website has a link at the footer of the page which gives them the option to go back to the desktop site if they choose to. But then i realized that the code written above on the main website will then again redirect the user back to the mobile website again. The mobile website is made using HTML/CSS and the main website is made using .asp classic. I was wondering if there was a way to make this happen so that the user can stay at the main website if they choose to.

Comment: Check out CSS media queries (much cleaner and easier); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a session object in Classic ASP to hide your javascript redirect

eg

```
<% session("usemainsite") = Request("usemainsite")
if session("usemainsite") <> 1 then %>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 1024) {
document.location = "mobilewebsite.html";
}
//-->
</script>

<% end if %>
```

You could use a querystring value in the link in your mobile site to set your session object to 1

Comment: Its not working for me. Can you review the modifications i made and see where i went wrong http://pastebin.com/Fs7XLLrF

Comment: Looking at the error message in http://users9.jabry.com/obdkey/About.asp?cmd=1 you appear to have a syntax error in the top two lines of code - the bit which starts with something like <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>

Answer (score 0):

instead of request("cmd") you need to put request.querystring("cmd")